# Is this a valid setup for tracking file ownership using Samba share and managing rights?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, samba4, shared-folders

Just need someone to look over my shoulder and tell me if this setup will work without any big problems down the road after I start adding users.

Current setup:

- Ubuntu 14.0.4LTS
- Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu
- External drive mounted in */etc/fstab* settings as */media/Backup01* with "ntfs-3g permissions,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8"
- Group *users* defined with intended SMB users as members and group sticky bit set in folder */media/Backup01/share*
- External WINS server, for what it's worth (192.168.0.4)
- Windows 7 and Windows 10 clients (with modified registry entries to allow them to join the domain)

**ls -l /media**

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug 13 14:13 Backup01
```

**ls -l /media/Backup01**

```
drwxrwsr-x 1 nobody users 152 Aug 17 09:12 share
```

**testparm**

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[netlogon]"
Processing section "[share]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_DOMAIN_PDC
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions
[global]
    workgroup = DOMAINNAME
    server string = %h PDC server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync = Yes
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    name resolve order = wins, lmhosts, hosts, bcast
    add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -N -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
    logon script = logon.cmd
    logon drive = H:
    domain logons = Yes
    preferred master = Yes
    domain master = Yes
    dns proxy = No
    wins server = 192.168.0.4
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775
[netlogon]
    comment = Network Logon Service
    path = /srv/samba/netlogon
    valid users = %S
    read only = No
    create mask = 0700
    directory mask = 0700
    guest ok = Yes
    browseable = No
[share]
    comment = Share
    path = /media/Backup01/share
    read only = No
    force create mode = 0664
    directory mask = 02775
    force directory mode = 02775
```

Seems to be working at the moment.

- Workstation can join the domain with SMB root's permission to do so
- User can map *share*, credentialing as DOMAINNAME\smbuser
- User can create a test file in the root
- Rights indicate that the user owns the file